# store array in vectors and sort the elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have a huge list of numbers in combination of three,

Is there a way to store these numbers in a vector as a unit and sort them for printing such that that combinations are sorted on the basis of first number, if that happens to have duplicate then they are further sorted on the basis of the second number and so on.

Here is an example for the input:

- 234 567 234
- 234 123 678
- 234 123 465
- 567 890 123

and for the expected output:

- 234 123 465
- 234 123 678
- 234 567 234
- 567 890 123

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` maybe?

Comment: - 234 567 234
 - 234 123 678
 - 234 123 465 
 - 567 890 123
..... say these are the inputs.
output should be
 - 234 123 465
 - 234 123 678 
 - 234 567 234
 - 567 890 123
.....

Comment: What code have you tried yourself? Seems to be a 2D vector with std::sort and a custom comparator?

Comment: For sorting, see e.g. [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Or `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>`. Yes, there are many ways. What have you tried?

Comment: i am trying to create a vector of pointers to array of integer but sorting it is a problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would basically need a two-d vector of integeres in here, and then you could use std::sort on it with a custom comparator.

```
bool vector_cmp(const vector<int> &v1, const vector<int> &v2)
{
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
        if (v1.at(i) < v2.at(i))
            return true;
        else if (v2.at(i) < v1.at(i))
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

vector<vector<int> > int2dVector;
// Append your internal vector in here
int2dVector << ... << ... << ...;

std::sort(int2dVector.begin(), int2dVector.end(), vector_cmp);
```

You could also write the last line simple just like this:

```
std::sort(int2dVector.begin(), int2dVector.end());
```

The reason for that is the [operator<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operators/) already exitsts for comparing vectors.

> Operations <, >, <= and >= behave as if using algorithm lexicographical_compare, which compares the elements sequentially using operator< reflexively, stopping at the first mismatch.

Disclaimer: it is completely untested and *only* proof of concept code.

Comment: is it applicable in the case when the number of keys in combination increases , say from three to 4 or 5...?? the number of keys in combination is user input..

Comment: @user3314983: yes, in fact, it is more flexible to that than a tuple.

Comment: does internal vector stores one integer value only......?? i am unable to understand .. can you explain it a bit..

Comment: Please read about [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Comment: @Jarod42: good points, updated. I used myfunction as that is what the manual used, too. :) I was also thinking about const reference earlier, but my laziness won. :P

Comment: Possible typo: `else if (v2.at(i) > v1.at(i))` might be `else if (v1.at(i) > v2.at(i))`

Comment: @Arun: oh, absolutely, thanks.

Comment: BTW, [bool operator <(const std::vector<T,A>&, const std::vector<T,A>&)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operators/) already exists.

Comment: @Jarod42: heh, good catch again...

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to define a proper comparison function is to use a **compare** function that return either negative, zero or positive. E.g. `std::string::compare` is one such.

Another way is to use [`std::lexicographic_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

E.g.,

```
struct Triple
{
    double values[3];
};

bool operator<( Triple const& a, Triple const& b )
{
    return std::lexicographic_compare(
        &a.values[0], &a.values[0] + 3,
        &b.values[0], &b.values[0] + 3
        );
}

void foo()
{
    vector<Triple> triples = ...;
    sort( triples.begin(), triples.end() );
}
```